# Show button only from monday to friday

Tags: php, date

I have written this simple code to display a button only from 10am to 3pm. It works fine like this, but it should not display the button on Satruday and Sunday.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');

$currentHour = date("H:i");
$day = date(format)
$openTime = "10:00";
$closeTime = "15:00";
if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentHour < $closeTime){
    $css = 'display:block;';
}else{
    $css = 'display:none;';
}

echo '<style type="text/css">.menudelgiorno {'.$css.'}</style>'; ?>
```

I'm a newbie in programming in general and it would help me a lot if anyone can give me some tipps.
Thank you!!

Comment: You can use [`date("D")`, `date("l")`, `date("N")`, `date("w")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the day of the week, depending on the value you want to compare to.

Comment: I'd use the `date('n')` and if greater than 5 don't display..

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! I'm just not sure yet hoe to use these parameters in my code. If you have an example, that would be awesome!

Comment: @chris85 I think you mean [`date('N')` *N - ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) - 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and not  [`date('n')` *n - Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros - 1 through 12*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: @Sean oh, yup that's the right version of that letter.

Comment: Seems like this one's another runaway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the day of the week, use the formatting option **N** which will return the ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

```
$dow = date("N") ;
if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentHour < $closeTime && $dow < 6){
    $css = 'display:block;';
}else{
    $css = 'display:none;';
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, works like a charm! Thank you so much everyone !!

Comment: @sniffles (Addendum to the above): Otherwise, people may want to add more answers and thinking the question is still open/unsolved and will remain in the unanswered category until you do.

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to do these thinks with Client Side Scripts like  Jquery

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
$currentHour = date("H:i");
$day = date(format)
$openTime = "10:00";
$closeTime = "15:00";
$css = 'display:none';
if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentHour < $closeTime && !in_array(date('w'), array(0,6))){
   $css = 'display:block';
}
echo '<style type="text/css">.menudelgiorno {'.$css.'}</style>'; ?>
```